# How to achieve parallelism for SharedArrayBuffer and Atomics?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, parallel-processing, shared-memory, ecmascript-2017

ECMA-2017(ES8), just finalized about a month ago, introduces [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) and [Atomics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics). The [link here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) shows that they have been supported in some browsers.

As we know, they are meant to allow the sharing of data across threads. I wonder how this kind of parallelism is achieved in browsers and Node? Are we supposed to use Web Workers and the 'cluster' package respectively?

Comment: Node is a single thread application, No?

Comment: Well, I think threads can be forked and made to run in parallel on separate cores with the 'cluster' package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, for browsers `SharedArrayBuffers` and `Atomics` are intended to be used [with WebWorkers](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md), which is the natural way to have code run in concurrent threads in a browser context.

For Node.js, the threads spawned with the cluster package would indeed be candidates for sharing data, but at the time of writing there is [no implementation of `SharedArrayBuffers`](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-shared-memory-and-atomics) in Node.js yet, so this is theory. You may want to scan several discussions about it:

- [Tracking issue: Worker support](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13143)
- [Does NodeJS have any plans for shared memory?](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/560)
- [High level architecture](https://github.com/nodejs/worker/issues/2)
- [Why is it so hard to add threads to nodejs? or web workers?](https://github.com/nodejs/worker/issues/4)

There already is the [ems](https://github.com/SyntheticSemantics/ems) package which allows sharing data between different threads and processes.

Related:

- [node-webworker-threads - Lightweight Web Worker API implementation with native threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads)

Comment: Node released a new version (v10.5.0) including experimental worker threads that can share instances of `ArrayBuffer` or `SharedArrayBuffer` : https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Answer (score 1):

For nodejs the SharedArrayBuffer And Array buffer havee been supported officially since v10.5.0 and they are directly mentioned on the documentation on https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html:

> Unlike child_process or cluster, worker_threads can share memory. They
> do so by transferring **ArrayBuffer** instances or sharing
> **SharedArrayBuffer** instances.

## Shared buffer and atomics:

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/the-return-of-sharedarraybuffers-and-atomics/

A good article that tackle directly the shared buffer. And the use with atomic (You must look at Atomic too).

Quick snippet (from the article):

```
    
// Creating a shared buffer
const length = 10;
 // Get the size we want in bytes for the buffer
const size = Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * length;
 // Create a buffer for 10 integers
const sharedBuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(size);
const sharedArray = new Int32Array(sharedBuffer);
```

Now we have a shared buffer that we can pass to a worker context and also have an integer Array that leverages that shared buffer. To pass this buffer reference to the worker:

```
// main.js
worker.postMessage(sharedBuffer);
```

This buffer allows us to create another shared array on the worker side:

```
// worker.js
constsharedArray = new Int32Array(m.data);
```

The article cover a lot of details and the use of atomic too. Check the last section too about the support in the browser! It may be outdated already! but still relevant!

Check **Introducing Atomics** title for a good introduction! (too long to site here).

And from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics. A link to check.

**And**

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-threads-in-node-js-4fa3898fe74f/

And this one take the whole multi-threading including the shared buffer use. With good historical background. And it tackle many many things.

**Check this too:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411795/7668448

For the use of data view!