# Node.js worker threads shared object/store

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker-thread

So, I was reading some stuff regarding Node.js and I was amazed when I came across [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Having threads in my opinion is a great plus especially if you combine it with shared memory access. As you might think already -> `SharedArrayBuffer`...

Yeap that's what I thought. So The first thing that came into my mind was to give it a little test and try to implement a simple `store` (a simple object for now) that would be shared among the threads.

The question is, (unless I'm missing something here) how can you make an object accessible from n threads with the use of `SharedArrayBuffer`?

I know that for a simple `Uint32Array` is doable, but regarding the object what can be done?

At first I thought to convert it to a `Uint32Array` as you may see bellow, but even looking at the damn source code makes me wanna cry...

```
const {
    Worker,
    isMainThread,
    workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

const store = {
    ks109: {
        title: 'some title 1',
        description: 'some desciption 1',
        keywords: ['one', 'two']
    },
    ks110: {
        title: 'some title 2',
        description: 'some desciption 2',
        keywords: ['three', 'four']
    },
    ks111: {
        title: 'some title 3',
        description: 'some desciption 3',
        keywords: ['five', 'six']
    }
}

const shareObject = (obj) => {

    let OString = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let SABuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * OString.length);
    let sArray = new Int32Array(SABuffer);

    for (let i = 0; i < OString.length; i++) {
        sArray[i] = OString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return sArray;

}

if (isMainThread) {

    const sharedStore = shareObject(store);

    console.log('[Main][Data Before]:', sharedStore.slice(-10));

    let w = new Worker(__filename, {
        workerData: sharedStore
    });

    w.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(`[Main][Thread message]: ${msg}`);
    });
    w.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`[Main][Thread error] ${err.message}`);
    });
    w.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            console.error(`[Main][Thread unexpected exit]: ${code}`);
        }
    });

    setInterval(() => {
        // At some point you ll see a value change,
        // it's 'six' becoming 'sax' (big time!) 
        console.log('[Main][Data Check]:', sharedStore.slice(-10));
    }, 1000);

} else {

    let str = String.fromCharCode.apply(this, workerData);
    let obj = JSON.parse(str);

    obj.ks111.keywords[1] = 'sax'; // big time!

    let OString = JSON.stringify(obj);

    for (let i = 0; i < OString.length; i++) {
        workerData[i] = OString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

}
```

In conclusion, shared object among threads in Node.js 10.5.0, is it possible? How?

Comment: From what I'm reading the only directly shared memory is a `SharedArrayBuffer` and it only contains raw binary data (not objects).  So, I don't see how you would directly share an object among threads.  Worker threads appear to work similar to web workers in the browser where there are not shared regular variables and they must communicate with other code via `postMessage()` (for synchronization reasons).

Comment: Putting a piece of JSON into a `SharedArrayBuffer` doesn't seem like it would help much other than just sharing a string.  Each worker would have to `JSON.parse()` the JSON into its own non-shared object.  This level of sharing could be done by just posting a message to each worker anytime someone wants to change the data so all workers have a copy of the same data.

Comment: The closest answer to sharedObjects in Node is probably here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519325/share-objects-in-nodejs-between-different-instances

Comment: Something that may be of interest is [comlink](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ECMA Script contains no shared objects but it has [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer). And you can implement such behavior on your own writing data directly in buffer using `DataView` and wrapper:

```
// Shared value
class SharedPoint {
  constructor(array) {
    this.dataview = new DataView(array);
  }

  set x(value) {
    this.dataview.setUint8(0, value);
  }

  set y(value) {
    this.dataview.setUint8(1, value);
  }

  get x() {
    return this.dataview.getUint8(0);
  }

  get y() {
    return this.dataview.getUint8(1);
  }
}

// Usage

const buffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(2);

// Create two instances of shared point.
const point0 = new SharedPoint(buffer);
const point1 = new SharedPoint(buffer);

// Get initial values for point #1
console.log('x', point1.x); // 0
console.log('y', point1.y); // 0

// Update point #0
point0.x = 64;
point0.y = 32;

// Get changes in point #1
console.log('x', point1.x); // 64
console.log('y', point1.y); // 32
```

You are able to create class which can manipulate strings or [C-like structures](https://github.com/firejune/struct.js/tree/master). While [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) is transferable object it can be shared between worker and main process.

> **⚠️ Note** Due to [Spectre attack](https://meltdownattack.com/) [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) was disabled by all major browsers and reenabled. Though the API is mature, its' support could be lower than one might expect. Check browsers support at [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=sharedarraybuffer).

Comment: any tool to convert JS Object to `SharedArrayBuffer `

Comment: anything NodeJS specific?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira if you want to be able to convert any js object then the best you can do is convert it to a json string, then convert that string to a buffer and then on the other side do the reverse

Answer (score 0):

No native solution, but you can create a `serializer/deserializer` that's backed by `SharedArrayBuffer`.

You can check [this](https://github.com/Ana73l/dark-star/tree/master/packages/shared-object) repo - a library I haven't yet published - it takes a schema (object structure) and (de)serializes it to (from) `ArrayBuffer` or `SharedArrayBuffer`. This can be used to serialize on `main thread` and deserialize on `worker thread` by passing buffers. It supports fixed arrays of objects and nested objects.

Comment: Have you benchmarked this solution towards standard postMessage copy of objects? Is there a significant improvement?

Answer (score -1):

The code can be written like below. It can be seen that in worker the object was changed after **parentPort.postMessage(sArray)**. This shows that threads use shared memory with **SharedArrayBuffer**

```
const {
    Worker,
    isMainThread,
    workerData,
    parentPort
} = require('worker_threads');

const store = {
    ks109: {
        title: 'some title 1',
        description: 'some desciption 1',
        keywords: ['one', 'two']
    },
    ks110: {
        title: 'some title 2',
        description: 'some desciption 2',
        keywords: ['three', 'four']
    },
    ks111: {
        title: 'some title 3',
        description: 'some desciption 3',
        keywords: ['five', 'six']
    }
}

if (isMainThread) {
    let w = new Worker(__filename, {
        workerData: store
    });

    w.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log("Received message from worker");
        const strArr = []
        for(let i = 0; i < data.byteLength; i++){
            strArr.push(String.fromCharCode(data.getUint8(i)));
        }
        console.log(JSON.parse(strArr.join("")))
    });
    w.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`[Main][Thread error] ${err.message}`);
    });
    w.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
            console.error(`[Main][Thread unexpected exit]: ${code}`);
        }
    });

} else {
    let OString = JSON.stringify(workerData);
    let SABuffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(OString.length);
    let sArray = new DataView(SABuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < OString.length; i++) {
        sArray.setUint8(i,OString.charCodeAt(i))
    }
    parentPort.postMessage(sArray);
    let index1 = OString.indexOf("ks111");
    const key1SubString = OString.substring(index1);
    let index2 = key1SubString.indexOf("keywords");
    const key2SubString = key1SubString.substring(index2);
    let index3 = key2SubString.indexOf("six");
    const newIndex = index1+index2+index3+1;
    sArray.setUint8(newIndex,'a'.charCodeAt());
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to share any memory or objects between threads, it relies on postMessage() to tranfer data